# How come I'm only seeing my jQuery media query changes when I refresh my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I have this weird issue where the only time my jQuery media query changes reflect on the browser is when I refresh the page.

If I go and check out another user agent after refreshing my page, that view (new user agent) also doesn't have the changes reflected on the browser.  I have to refresh the page to see those changes reflected.

Below's a small snippet of some jQuery code.  What could be the issue?

```
var amount = 2;

function func() {
  if(amount > 0) {
     this.theStyle(amount);
  }

}



function theStyle(amount) {
   if(amount > 0) {

    if($(window).width() >= 667 && $(window).width() <= 736) {
        $('.tagOne, .tagTwo').css('padding-bottom', '99.6%');

        $('.tagThree').css({
            'position' : 'relative',
            'bottom' : '0.3rem'
        })

        $('tagFour').css({
            'position' : 'relative',
            'top' : '4px'
        });
    }

    if($(window).width() >= 780 && $(window).width() <= 811) {
        $('.tagFive, .tagSix').css('padding-bottom', '99.7%');
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Where are you running this code? Does it run only once? Or inside an event listener for the “resize” event?

Comment: @TomJardine-McNamara What's happening is - the `amount` variable is coming from another function that gets executed only once.  It's not inside an event listener for the `resize` event.  Hopefully I cleared it up for you a little, I've updated my snippet above.

Comment: how is `theStyle` function called?

Comment: @someone If I understand correctly you’re asking why you don’t see the css changes applied by your JS code when you resize the viewport (possibly using dev tools to select different device presets?). If `theStyle` is only called once, then that’s why. 

If you want `theStyle` to be run on resize, add an event listener for it: `document.addEventListener(‘resize’, theStyle)`. You may wish to debounce the calls so they don’t run for every single change while a use resizes the viewport.

Comment: @Bravo I've updated my snippet to illustrate what I mean :).

Comment: so how is `function func` called (this could get tedious if `func` is called exactly once)

Comment: @Bravo yeah it's called exactly once.  for our case, we could assume it gets called like this `this.func();`.

Comment: yes, but read ALL the comments - if you call the function once, it gets executed once ... it doesn't magically get executed when *something changes* unless you listen for events to indicate that *something has changed* - for example, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener

Comment: Create jsfiddle with jQuery and I would be glad to help.